# See no Items after adding them

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

My Listview show nothing after adding Items from a List into it. Why?
My List is not empty And my program goes into this loop.
So Is the code wrong for adding items into an listview? Because I saw many chatrooms and also from Microsoft that I can add them like this.

[image]

I tried it also with this code:`listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageKey = "Person", Text = database1[counter1].name });`

Here a picture of my imglist, and the list is chosen at thelistview:
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8mjf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add items if there are no columns, or you can but they wont show up.
Have you added some columns to your listView?

```
//Adds needed columns
this.listView1.Columns.Add("<column_name>", 50);
```

If you have one column, you can simply add items by:

```
ListViewItem itm = new ListViewItem("my_item");
listView1.Items.Add(itm);
```

If you have multiple columns instead of a string, you can do the same but with a string array where the array size equals to the number of columns.

```
string[] items = new string[listView1.Columns.Count];
```

Try this in your code too, in my code only works with this:

```
this.listView1.View = View.Details;
```

Comment: Haven't columns. Thx I will try it.